# ¿como calculo la hipotenusa en python?

Tags: python

Tiene que dar error si algun cateto es menor o igual a 0
llevo escrito esto:

```
cateto1 = int(input("Introduce valor cateto a: "))
cateto1**=2
cateto2 = int(input("Introduce valor cateto b: "))
cateto2**=2
hipo = cateto1 + cateto2
if (cateto1 <= 0 or cateto2 <= 0):
    print("ERROOOOR")
else:
    print(hipo)
```

con la hipotenusa no se seguir

Comment: Hola Jacinto, ¿que es exactamente lo que te impide seguir?

Comment: hay un pequeño problema en la forma en que estás calculando la hipotenusa. El cálculo de la hipotenusa debe ser la raíz cuadrada de la suma de los cuadrados de los catetos, no solo la suma de los cuadrados.

Comment: hola FJSevilla, pues que no se hacer una raiz cuadrada en codigo

Comment: Con la última edición el código se responde solo. Marca la respuesta que te sirvió la con el tilde ✓

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular la raíz cuadrada puedes importa la librería `math`

```
import math
math.sqrt(25) # 5.0
```

Esta forma es muy común en varios lenguajes

Por otro lado existe el operador potencia `**` y dado que la raíz cuadrada es lo mismo que elevar a `1/2` (o 0.5), también resulta hacer:

```
25 ** (1/2) #5.0
```

Por último, debes recordar que todo número elevado al cuadrado es positivo por lo que tu `if` en la práctica no está validando los negativos

```
cateto1 = int(input("Introduce valor cateto a: "))
cateto1**=2
cateto2 = int(input("Introduce valor cateto b: "))
cateto2**=2
hipo = cateto1 + cateto2
if (cateto1 <= 0 or cateto2 <= 0): # Esta condición solo se cumple cuando ambos catetos son cero, NO estas validando los números negativos
    print("ERROOOOR")
else:
    print(hipo)
```

La validación debes realizar antes de elevar al cuadrado

```
cateto1 = int(input("Introduce valor cateto a: "))
cateto2 = int(input("Introduce valor cateto b: "))
if (cateto1 <= 0 or cateto2 <= 0):
    print("ERROOOOR")
else:
   cateto1**=2
   cateto2**=2
   hipo = (cateto1 + cateto2) ** 0.5
   print(hipo)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef

Answer (score 0):

creo que he encontrado la solucion
`cateto1 = int(input("Introduce valor cateto a: "))
cateto2 = int(input("Introduce valor cateto b: "))

if cateto1 <= 0 or cateto2 <= 0:
print("ERROR: Los catetos deben ser mayores que cero.")
else:
hipo = (cateto1**2 + cateto2**2)** 0.5
print("La hipotenusa es:", hipo)`